# MySQL connections not closing

Tags: mysql, connections

I have a web application running on Tomcat7 that connects to MySQL 5.5.

I have two servers running the identical code:

- Ubuntu
- Red Hat

The Ubuntu one runs fine maintaining a steady 8-16 connections, but the Red Hat one leaks connections and the connection count grows, never going down.  The server eventually resets ~152 connections and the cycle repeats.

The code to close the connection is getting called:

```
try {
    conn.close();           
} catch (SQLException e) {
    exceptionController.logException(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "finalize Db", e.getMessage(), false);
}finally{
    conn = null;
}
```

Why the difference in behavior?  Are there configuration settings that I should be condsidering?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out RedHat has it's own MySQL folders.  My config file in the default `/etc/my.cnf` was not being consumed.